# Push Messages using REST api in android

Tags: android, rest, parse-platform

I am developing an Android app using Parse.com website. In which whatever user sends data that must be received by receiver, but here I have to use REST api. I succeeded to send data to Parse website but now I have to Push that data with the help of REST api only. I am confused with REST api. Help to solve it.

Comment: what problem you are facing in code? Have u tried implementing it

Comment: There are ways to do it and it is explained in the tutorial page. https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide

Comment: actuallu I am not getting how to start with REST api. If you know some tutotrials regarding this then send me the link.

Comment: but I have to use REST api only.

Comment: you can find this also in the tutorials check 
https://www.parse.com/docs/rest

Comment: I want to ask you that Is it necessary to make JSON webservice??

Comment: JSON is much easier and efficient way to deal with.

Comment: I am asking that is it compulsary to make JSON webservice with REST api???

Comment: Yes!! you need to use JSON webservice

Comment: Ok. But now my question is how can I deal with Parse.com website? Means, my data are on Parse.com website and I want to retrieve them on android device in app using REST api??

Comment: ok, use restdroid to set up rest api implementations 
https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid
 and then use the library to invoke data as given in the examples in this page
https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#objects-retrieving

Comment: I am not getting about your given solution.can you explain??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library for that. I would suggest this one https://github.com/kodart/Httpzoid
It has clean API and type-safe data.

Here is a simple usage example

```
Http http = HttpFactory.create(context);
http.post("http://example.com/users")
    .data(new User("John"))
    .execute();
```

Or more complex with callbacks

```
Http http = HttpFactory.create(context);
http.post("http://example.com/users")
    .data(new User("John"))
    .handler(new ResponseHandler<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Void ignore, HttpResponse response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void error(String message, HttpResponse response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(NetworkError error) {
        }

        @Override
        public void complete() {
        }
    }).execute();
```

It is fresh new, but looks very promising.